# Virtual column not allowed here

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to insert a row in a table using `VIEW` as

```
INSERT INTO FIELDI18N(LANGUAGE_ID) VALUES (1);
```

but it gives me following error:

```
Error starting at line 5 in command:
INSERT INTO FIELDI18N(LANGUAGE_ID) VALUES (1)
Error at Command Line:5 Column:22
Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-01733: virtual column not allowed here
01733. 00000 -  "virtual column not allowed here"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

Any Clue ?

Added the View Definition:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW FIELDI18N("FIELDID", "NAME", "TYPE", "DESCRIPTION", "LANGUAGE_ID")
AS
  (SELECT field.fieldid,
    field.type,
    NVL(i18n.name, field.name) name,
    NVL(i18n.description, field.description) description,
    i18n.language_id
  FROM fields field
  JOIN i18n_fields i18n
  ON (field.fieldid    = i18n.fieldid)
  );
```

Comment: Please post the create view and table statements for the objects affected by this.

Comment: A view with a join is not updateable unless you create an `INSTEAD OF` trigger. For details see the manual: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/statements_8004.htm#SQLRF54782 and here http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25494/views.htm#ADMIN11782

Answer (score 5):

LANGUAGE_ID is probably a calculated field, or in any case the database cannot infer what change is to be made to the tables underlying the view based on the change you are requiring. Have to see the view definition code to know.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that in order to do an insert or update using a view that all of the tables in the view must be joined via a primary key. This is to prevent duplicates caused by the view which cannot be updated.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a very good reason you are not just inserting into the underlying table?  If you can, just insert into the table directly and avoid this complication.

What are you expecting Oracle to do?  Are you expecting it to insert a new record into `i18n_fields`?

If you really want to do it like this you will need to create an INSTEAD OF trigger because Oracle can't figure out which of the underlying tables it should insert into when your run your insert statement.

Comment: Yes, it has to be inserted through views.